# How to design/shape a polyhedron to be nearly spherically symmetrical, but not a platonic solid?

Tags: geometry, platonic-solids

There are only 5 platonic solids, but take a look at these images:

[image]
[image]

How are these things designed? How are they shaped? It looks to me like those hexagons are all the same size and shape, and evenly distributed to approximate a sphere. Same thing with the triangles in the second picture.

So how is it possible? Are some of the hexagons actually slightly smaller or irregular? Can someone show me in the blueprint exactly where the properties of a platonic solid are NOT met?

Comment: The latter of these is called a ["geodesic dome"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_dome). In particular, you have a picture there of the attraction called Spaceship Earth at Epcot. Web searches for either should get you lots of information about the design of such things. As you suspect, the constituent parts are slightly irregular.

Comment: It's possible to make a sphere-like shape from hexagons and pentagons, which is probably what's going on in the first picture. Any such shape must have exactly twelve pentagons.

Comment: Similarly, you can have a sphere-like shape from near-equilateral triangles. All vertices must have six edges coming out of them, except for exactly twelve, which will have five edges coming out of them. This is probably the deal with the second picture. (In addition, they seem to have placed little pyramids on each face. This is called the Kleetope of the original figure.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw is it possible to make a sphere-like shape from only hexagons? Preferably as regular as possible. Symmetry in the number of adjacent faces is important to me because I want a globular game board. If it had some pentagons, those cells would be rather undesirable since they could only lead to 5 moves instead of 6.

Comment: @DrZ214 Let's say we have three hexagons meeting at every vertex, which is probably what you want. Let $F$ be the number of faces. Since every hexagon has six edges, we'd think that there are $6F$ edges — however, we just counted each edge twice (once from each neighboring hexagon), so there are only $3F$ edges. Similarly, each face has six vertices, but we just counted each vertex three times, so we have $2F$ vertices. Plug into Euler's polyhedron formula, $V-E+F=2$, and we have $2F-3F+F=2$, or $0=2$. Contradiction!

Comment: On the other hand, I believe you can make a good doughnut shape ("torus") from just hexagons. Euler's formula doesn't apply to things with holes.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Euler's formula totally applies to things with holes, it's just that the right-hand side becomes $2-2g$, where $g$ is the number of holes. See [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic).

Comment: To build on Rahul's comment and columbus's calculation: The fact that the one-holed torus has Euler characteristic $2-2\cdot 1 = 0$ is what makes an all-hexagons grid on that surface feasible. Indeed, [this Gamasutra article about hex grids](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/HermanTulleken/20140912/225495/20_Fun_Grid_Facts_Hex_Grids.php) shows (as "Fact #5") how to wrap a single hexagon around a torus, pasting vertices and edges together so that $V = 2$, $E = 3$, $F=1$. (Nevermind that a single space doesn't make for much fun as a game grid. :)

Comment: If you want identical faces for a game board so that all tiles have similar move possibilities, the Catalan solids may also work (which, coincidentally, form a large class of fair dice shapes...).

Comment: @pjs36 I took a look at the Catalans, especially the Pentagonal hexecontahedron. Can't you make even bigger Catalans by splitting up each face into multiple triangles? Come to think of it, can't you do this same thing for a Platonic like the Dodecahedron or Icosahedron? Then you would have additional Platonic solids...which isn't possible...but why won't this work?

Comment: @DrZ214 I'm not sure how familiar you are with polyhedra, but it's subtle; all of these various shapes have precise definitions, and variations don't *quite* fit those same definitions. I'll try and post a more fleshed-out answer within a day or so.

Comment: @DrZ214 Some among these are the (so-called)  *geodesic domes*  created by Buckminster Fuller. The designation starts from the number of subdivisions made on a side of the regular icosahedron.

Answer (score 6):

When you see a polyhedron like that, if it's not a platonic solid, then either the faces are not congruent or not exactly regular. There are many ways to do this. Usually they take a platonic solid, like the icosahedron or the dodecahedron and start [truncating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_(geometry)) it or subdividing the faces into more polygons and then elevating the vertices to touch the original polyhedron's [circumbscribed sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_sphere) (like a [kleetope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleetope), for example).

### The first image

Not all faces are hexagons:

[image: rolls-royce]

This is a [Goldberg polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron) with [Conway notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation) [cctl](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10cctI):

[image]

### The second image

Even ignoring the [stellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellation) (which makes the polyhedra non-convex), the triangles you're left with are not equilateral.

Constructing the [Epcot dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_Earth_(Epcot)) is a bit complicated. You start with a dodecahedron and build its kleetope, which is the [pentakis dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentakis_dodecahedron):

[image]

Alternatively, you can build this by starting with an icosahedron and building the dodecahedron as its [dual polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polyhedron). The triangles are isosceles, but not equilateral—they differ in length by approximately 10%. This is excellent, because it looks almost regular to the naked eye.

Now you start a recursive construction of subdividing each triangle into 4 like this:

[image]

and raising the vertices to touch the original polyhedron's circumbscribed sphere.

The first iteration gives:

[image]

Notice the position of the pentagons. The second iteration gives:

[image]

And finally:

[image]

The image above corresponds to the Epcot dome without the pyramids that make it non-convex.

Here is the dome with the first iteration highlighted:

[image]

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhtFD.jpg) for higher resolution.

In computer graphics, they call these polyhedra with triangular faces [icospheres](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uv-sphere-and-an-icosphere).

Here's the (badly written) Matlab code for plotting the Epcot dome:

```
phi = 0.5*(1+sqrt(5));
%%%%%%%% Icosahedron %%%%%%%%
Pc = [phi,1,0; -phi,1,0; phi,-1,0; -phi,-1,0;
      1,0,phi; 1,0,-phi; -1,0,phi; -1,0,-phi;
      0,phi,1; 0,-phi,1; 0,phi,-1; 0,-phi,-1]';
Pc = Pc/sqrt(1+phi^2);

%%%%%%%% Pentakis Dodecahedron %%%%%%%%
K = convhull(Pc(1,:),Pc(2,:),Pc(3,:));
Ksize = size(K);
for n=1:Ksize(1)
    x = Pc(1,K(n,:));
    y = Pc(2,K(n,:));
    z = Pc(3,K(n,:));
    [az,el,r] = cart2sph(mean(x),mean(y),mean(z));
    [x,y,z] = sph2cart(az,el,1);
    Pc = [Pc [x;y;z]];
end

MaxSubdiv = 3; %Change to 0, 1, 2 or 3 (3 is VERY slow)
%%%%%%%% Subdivisions %%%%%%%%
for subdiv = 1:MaxSubdiv
    K = convhull(Pc(1,:),Pc(2,:),Pc(3,:));
    Ksize = size(K);
    for n=1:Ksize(1)
        x = Pc(1,K(n,:));
        y = Pc(2,K(n,:));
        z = Pc(3,K(n,:));
        [az,el,r] = cart2sph(0.5*(x(1)+x(2)),0.5*(y(1)+y(2)),0.5*(z(1)+z(2)));
        [xnew,ynew,znew] = sph2cart(az,el,1);
        Pc = [Pc [xnew;ynew;znew]];
        [az,el,r] = cart2sph(0.5*(x(2)+x(3)),0.5*(y(2)+y(3)),0.5*(z(2)+z(3)));
        [xnew,ynew,znew] = sph2cart(az,el,1);
        Pc = [Pc [xnew;ynew;znew]];
        [az,el,r] = cart2sph(0.5*(x(3)+x(1)),0.5*(y(3)+y(1)),0.5*(z(3)+z(1)));
        [xnew,ynew,znew] = sph2cart(az,el,1);
        Pc = [Pc [xnew;ynew;znew]];
    end
end

%%%%%%%% PLOT %%%%%%%%
hold off
K = convhull(Pc(1,:),Pc(2,:),Pc(3,:));
Ksize = size(K);
for n=1:Ksize(1)
    x = Pc(1,K(n,:));
    y = Pc(2,K(n,:));
    z = Pc(3,K(n,:));
    h = fill3(x,y,z,[.3,.4,1]);
    set(h,'LineWidth',1);
    axis equal;
    hold on
end
alpha(0.85);
```

Comment: Cool pics! ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

**Some Hint**:  In order to design a polyhedron with faces evenly distributed to approximate a sphere, either a solid sphere or a spherical shell with a certain radius is taken 
such that sum of the spherical areas of all faces on the sphere is equal to the total surface area of sphere.

then the faces of required dimensions can be generated by facing operations with the help of (automated) machines/robots etc. Thus all the vertices of the faces will  lie approximately on a sphere.

Picture 1: The hexagonal faces are evenly distributed to approximate a sphere but they all need not be regular in shape i.e. some may regular & some irregular in shape as well. In this case, three hexagonal faces meet at each vertex. There is only one convex regular polyhedron called truncated icosahedron having 20 congruent regular hexagons & 12 regular pentagons all of equal edge length.

Picture 2: The polyhedron shown is a non convex polyhedron in which has 6 stellar triangular faces are generated on each of hexagonal faces as in picture 1. Thus pyramid like stellar faces have regular triangular base & lateral faces as isosceles triangles. faces of one hexagonal groove need not be identical to that of other hexagonal groove. 
As far as the regular triangular shapes are concerned there is only one regular convex polyhedron called Icosahedron (platonic solid)  having 20 congruent equilateral triangular faces.