# How to apply Euler's formula to polyhedra with pentagons and hexagons

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I have just started with polyhedra (know Euler's formula etc..) not sure how to approach this?

A shape has faces only consisting of P regular pentagons (all of the same size), and H regular hexagons (all of the same size), and subject to the rule that at each corner meet two hexagons and one pentagon.

How can I find the number of faces?

Comment: if the polygons are regular it is a soccer ball, that is it. Allowing slightly less regular polygons allows for the Goldberg polyhedra,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron

Comment: I can tell it is a soccer ball, but how can I prove the number of faces using edges and vertices

Comment: The asked for truncated icosahedron rather is an archimedean polyhedron than a complex polyhedron. You probably used "complex" for "complicated". But remember, there are complex numbers too, and H.S.M. Coxeter already introduced "complex polytopes" for polytopes within complex spaces. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_polytope. In fact, a 0D complex element is a point. A 1D complex element has 2 real dimensions (cf. the Argand plane). A complex 2D element has 4 real dimensions, etc. An nD complex polytope is representable as an 2nD real space polytope, using even-D elements only.

Comment: @Will Jagy (thanks to Wikipedia) I just had access to the original paper of M. Goldberg in Tohoku Mathematical Journal Vol. 43 (1937) "A Class of Multisymmetric Polyhedra" https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/43/0/43_0_104/_pdf/-char/en very interesting...

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you, that is very nice, and new to me.

Comment: Related and interesting : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1987174

Comment: Set apart the soccer ball, I have some doubts about the existence of such  polyhedra with all their hexagons of the same size.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order that, further on, this question and its answer attracts attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the number of faces is $P + H$. But I suppose you want a number.

Euler's formula is $V+F = 2+E$. As three faces meet at every vertex of the polyhedron and there are $6H + 5P$ vertices total (of the faces individually), each vertex of the polyhedron is counted thrice there and so 
$$V = \frac{6H+5P}{3}.$$
Each edge of the polyhedron is shared by two faces and there are $6H + 5P$ edges (of the faces individually), each edge of the polyhedron is counted twice there and so 
$$E = \frac{6H+5P}{2}.$$
Now you can use Euler's formula to find an expression for $F$. It will be different from the obvious expression $F=P+H$. You'll be able to solve for everything.

Added later: so you know $P=12$. We haven't fully used that one hexagon and two pentagons meet at every vertex -- we've only used that three faces meet at each vertex. This tells you that the total number of vertices of the polyhedron is equal to the number of vertices of of all the pentagons combined, which is $12\cdot 5 = 60$. So $V = 60$. Now you can solve for $H$.

Comment: Hi could you elaborate how to get a value for H? Not sure if I am being stupid but I have a value for P. (P=12) but cannot get any further? Thank you!

Comment: I'll add to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, understood now!

Comment: On a side note, the equality $E = \frac{6H+5P}{2}$can "alternatively" be derived by observing that the average degree $d$ of the respective planar graph is $3$. By the handshaking lemma $E= \frac{V \cdot d}{2}$ the equality then follows.