# How can I define a Goldberg polyhedral with nearly-regular hexagons, given a hexagon width and sphere circumference?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, spherical-geometry, discrete-geometry

I'm trying to create a "hexagonal grid" that covers the planet earth with *nearly* regular hexagons.

I understand that, by including 12 pentagons, the remainder of a sphere can be covered by pseudo-hexagons (a Goldberg polyhedral), but not *regular* hexagons.

In my application, the hexagon width will be ~1 meter (and the earth's circumference is about 40 million meters) so I'm hoping that, because my  hexagon width to globe circumference ratio is so large, that I can cover the globe in *nearly* regular hexagons, and that the hexagon width deviation will be negligible.

Is there a function that could yield the parameters of such a Goldberg polyhedral, given a hexagon width? And is there a similar function that can tell me, for those parameters, what the standard deviation for the hexagon width is?

I'm guessing that such a function will be **discrete** rather than **continuous**. In other words, I'm guessing that there may be a finite set of values for hexagon width that have a solution.

I've read a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987174/can-a-polyhedron-made-solely-of-regular-pentagons-and-regular-hexagons-be-made) and I understand that there is no solution that yields *regular* hexagons, but as I mentioned above, my application doesn't require strictly regular hexagons, so long as their irregularity is negligible.

Ideally, this function would be limited to Goldberg polyhedra that have vertices connected by a series of flat-to-flat hexagons, like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geodesic_polyhedra_and_Goldberg_polyhedra#/media/File:Conway_polyhedron_dk6k5adk6k5adk6k5at5daD.png):
[image]